# User is null in the Google Cloud Api

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I followed the instructions in this tutorial.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/auth

when i deployed my code. and went to test my app.

with the following url

http://chandru-compute.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer

My 
helloworld.greetings.multiply and 
 helloworld.greetings.getGreeting works as expected.

But i have issues with the helloworld.greetings.authed method.

The user object is always null.

Here is the code.

```
package com.google.devrel.samples.helloendpoints;

import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.User;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceFactory;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
 * Defines v1 of a helloworld API, which provides simple "greeting" methods.
 */
@Api(
    name = "helloworld",
    version = "v1",
    clientIds = {com.google.api.server.spi.Constant.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID}
)
public class Greetings {
  public static ArrayList<Greeting> greetings = new ArrayList<Greeting>();
  static {
    greetings.add(new Greeting("hello world!"));
    greetings.add(new Greeting("goodbye world!"));
  }

  public Greeting getGreeting(@Named("id") Integer id) {
    return greetings.get(id);
  }

   @ApiMethod(name = "greetings.multiply", httpMethod = "post")
   public Greeting insertGreeting(@Named("times") Integer times, Greeting greeting) {
     Greeting response = new Greeting();
     StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
     for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
     responseBuilder.append(greeting.getMessage());
    }
    response.setMessage(responseBuilder.toString());
    return response;
  }

 @ApiMethod(name = "greetings.authed", path = "greeting/authed")
 public Greeting authedGreeting(User user) {
   //Greeting response = new Greeting("hello " + user.getEmail());
  Greeting response;
   if (user == null) {
       UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
       User user2 = userService.getCurrentUser();
       String text = null;
       if (user2 != null){
           text = user2.getEmail();
       }
       response = new Greeting("hello world : Email2" + text );
   } else {
       response = new Greeting("hello world : Email " + user.getEmail() );
   }
   return response;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

I had same problem, it helped for me to add

`scopes = {"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"}`

into my `Greetings` `@Api` annotation. So the whole final `@Api`look like

```
@Api(
 name = "helloworld", 
 version = "v1", 
 clientIds = { com.google.api.server.spi.Constant.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID }, 
 scopes = {"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"}
)
```

Then deploy, reload Api Explorer page and also turn on "Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0" option with same scope.

Comment: For me, I had the `scopes` set but not the API Explorer client-ID.

Answer (score 1):

I am getting the same problem. And if you throw an `OAuthRequestException` Exception and test the service via the API Explorer console, you will get a message saying `This method requires you to be authenticated. You may need to activate the toggle above to authorize your request using OAuth 2.0`. When you try to enable the OAuth 2.0 toggle it requests in a new window to Select OAuth 2.0 scopes, and I have not been able to find which scopes are needed or figure out how I can test a cloud end-point service with authorization from the API Explorer console.

Comment: how's now? I'm getting the same error message. in the end, how did you manage to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in the API explorer, you need to authenticate the request with OAuth using the *Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0* toggle in the user interface.

If the user is still null check that among the client ids there is the ID for the API explorer

```
@Api(
  name = "myAPIName", 
  version = "v1", 
  clientIds = { com.google.api.server.spi.Constant.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID }
)
```

This is the only thing that is needed to obtain a not null User argument.